# Why doesn't SO track review queue rankings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For reputation, the reputation leagues track year wise, month wise and week wise rankings.

How can I find the reviewer review ranks? The review screen (*Top Reviewers all time*) displays only top 20 users.

Any other option available to find the a reviewer's ranks?

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

Because we don't need to encourage people to review more just to "win" a game.

Poor reviewers can hurt the site by approving bad edits, letting Spam through, not providing good feedback to new users, and clearing posts out of a review queue before good reviewers can even see them.  This causes crap to sit around, possibly unnoticed for a long period of time.

So providing more options for "ranking" just adds more gamification to the site, and provides more incentive for someone to review as many as possible as quickly as possible, without regards to the quality of the review

Comment: To that effect, we could wonder _why_ you can see this ranking in the first place.